# Vue Liquor Tree not loading data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get a tree menu built using [Liquor Tree](https://amsik.github.io/liquor-tree/):

### HTML

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type to filter..." v-model="menu_filter" class="filter-field" />
<tree :data="$root.menu_tree" :options="menu_options" :filter="menu_filter"></tree>
```

### JS

```js
menu_options: {
  checkbox: false,
  minFetchDelay: 1000,
  fetchData(node) {
    return axios.get("/assets/data/fetch0/data.json");
  },
  filter: { emptyText: "Nothing!" }
}
```

The component renders but clicking on elements does nothing. No errors either. It was supposed to load node children from that URL but nothing happens.

I have also tried setting `fetchData` to a string, eg:

```js
menu_options: {
  checkbox: false,
  minFetchDelay: 1000,
  fetchData: "/assets/data/fetch0/data-{node.text}.json",
  filter: { emptyText: "Nothing!" }
}
```

Still nothing. Am I doing something wrong or is this thing broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your dom is not getting updated, to start `console.log` after the change so see if indeed it is changed. If that's the case you need to cause the `tree` to rerender this can be accomplished in a few ways, you can make the changed property a `computed` which should trigger a change, if that does not work make a key and change the key on data change. See here for a full explanation of forcing rerenders.
https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render

Comment: Seems like it’s not making the request at all. I tried having fetchData function send the request, it doesn’t get triggered at all.

Comment: Where are you calling the `fetchData` function?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to call it on its own?